# Creating a vector to store a queue

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, queue

I am really struggling on how to implement a vector into my program to store my data and priority level so i can access them later.  I have tried a couple of ways but they result in several errors, can someone lend me a hand.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T1>
class PriQueue
{
    public:

    vector<T1> tasks; // My vector which does absolutely NOTHING right now

    PriQueue();
    void enqueue(T1 str, int pri); //Adds to queue
    void setStr(T1 newStr);
    void setPri(int newPri);
    T1 getStr();
    T1 getPri();
    void dequeue(T1 str, int pri); //Deletes from queue
    void peek(); //Prints the the first in queue
    void size(); //Prints how many in queue

    //T1 printQ();

    private:

    T1 s;
    T1 p;

};

template <class T1>
PriQueue<T1>::PriQueue()
{

}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::enqueue(T1 str, int pri) //Adding an element to the queue
{
    this->s = str;
    this->p = pri;
    tasks.push_back(s); //If I do this, how would I print the front most item?
    tasks.push_back(p);

}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::setStr(T1 newStr)
{


    this->s = newStr;


}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::setPri(int newPri)
{

    this->p = newPri;


}

template <class T1>
T1 PriQueue<T1>::getStr()
{
    return s;

}

template <class T1>
T1 PriQueue<T1>::getPri()
{
    return p;

}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::dequeue(T1 str, int pri) //Removing an element from the front of the queue
{


}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::peek() //Returning a value at front of the queue (NOT removing it)
{
    for (auto& v : tasks)
    cout << v << endl;

}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::size() //Returning the number of items in the queue.
{


}


int main()
{
    string more;
    string task;
    int priority;

    do {

        PriQueue<string> que;

        cout << "What is your task in one word?" << endl;
        cin >> task;
        que.setStr(task);

        cout << "What is the priority level of the task on a scale of 1 to 10 (1 has the highest priority)?" << endl;
        cin >> priority;
        que.setPri(priority);


        //cout << que.getStr() << endl; //Test #1
        //cout << que.getPri() << endl; //Test #2

        cout << "Would you like to add another task (y/n)?" << endl;
        cin >> more;


    } while (more == "y" || more == "Y" || more == "Yes" || more == "yes");

que.peek();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be clear, this is a school assignment and you can't just use `std::priority_queue<T1>`? Also, please properly indent your code.

Comment: It's good that you had a go, but you should list exactly what the errors are, what you hoped/expected to happen, what you don't understand about how to achieve that....

Comment: @TonyD Lets say I implement list.push_back(s); list.push_back(p); in my enqueue function how would I go about printing all that is stored in my vector?

Comment: @user260739 - Don't call your member variable `list`.  There is already a `std::list` container in C++.

Comment: @user260739: "how would I go about printing all that is stored in my vector?" - if you have C++11, then `for (auto& v : list) std::cout << v << '\n';`.  Otherwise, `for (std::vector<T>::const_iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i) std::cout << v << '\b';`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie alright fixed, thank you

Comment: @TonyD alright each time I run my code past the "Would you like to add another task" my first task disappears.  Unless I did not place the code to print out in the correct place

Comment: @TonyD - I think it's time for you to use the debugger and step through your code using it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I believe that comment was meant for me, I will do this now.

Comment: @user260739 that is because `PriQueue<string> que;` appears inside the scope of the `do { } while ()` loop... it gets destroyed and recreated on every loop iteration.  You should move it before `do`.

Comment: @TonyD Placing the vector out code inside my peek function appears to not be printing anything.  I will change my code above to what I have now.

Comment: @user260739 - 1) Your `peek` function is defined differently in your class and in your implementation.  The class has a 0-argument version, while the implementation has 2 arguments   2) The `que` is a local variable that doesn't exist outside of that do-while() block in main().

Comment: @user260739: you're never calling `enqueue`, and further `enqueue` is written to accept the values as function arguments, so you should store them in variables local to the `do while` loop then call `enqueue`, without calling `setStr` or `setPri`, or alternatively add an `enqueue` version with no parameters that uses the currently set `s` and `p` values (but that would be a clumsy interface design).

Comment: @TonyD Is there anyway you could show me how this could work with actual code written out?

Comment: user260739: `do { std::string task; int priority; ...read them...; que.enqueue(task, priority); ...ask whether there're more...' } while (...);`